# Trying to use papaparse with vue

Tags: javascript, npm, vue.js, npm-install, papaparse

I am trying to use Papaparse to parse a csv file with vue but I am having trouble installing it. I am using npm to install papaparse and I use the command:
`npm install papaparse`
However, npm gives me these warnings:
`WARN uiv@0.11.11 requires a peer of bootstrap@^3.3.7 but none was installed.`
and `WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})`. From this, I assume it needs me to use bootstrap but on papaparse, it states that it does not require any dependencies? How can I properly install papaparse so that I may use it on my vue project?

Comment: Do you have any other packages installed? You might have better luck asking on the issues page https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse/issues.

Comment: You can ignore the second warning. The `fsevents` package is not being installed because is for MacOS only (https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12497).

Answer (score 0):

I only added the papaparse.min.js file to my web project and added to the bundleConfig, compile and

```
Papa.parse
```

worked instantly.

Only be careful with the routes where the file was saved.